# RestEasy client inside Tomee service

Tags: resteasy, apache-tomee

I have a RestEasy client I would like to use within a REST service deployed to Tomee.  Everything builds fine but at deployment time I get the error

```
fable-service>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FormUrlEncodedProvider is not a SERVER provider
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.isNotServerProvider(CxfRsHttpListener.java:491)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.providers(CxfRsHttpListener.java:434)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.configureFactory(CxfRsHttpListener.java:1009)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication(CxfRsHttpListener.java:577)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.deployApplication(RESTService.java:481)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:288)
fable-service>  at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxRsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxRsService.java:53)
fable-service>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
fable-service>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
fable-service>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
fable-service>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke(ObserverManager.java:406)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$InvocationList.invoke(ObserverManager.java:521)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.doFire(ObserverManager.java:111)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:100)
fable-service>  at org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:134)
fable-service>  at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.afterStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1746)
fable-service>  at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:116)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
fable-service>  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
fable-service>  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
fable-service>  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
fable-service>  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
fable-service>  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
fable-service>  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried playing with different versions of RestEasy and Tomee but the error doesn't change.  Currently I'm using RestEasy 3.5.1.Final inside the tomee:8-jre-7.0.4-plus Docker container.

Unfortunately, Google is not helping me get a handle on the issue either...

Comment: I got this working...but in a rather hackish way :(  The root problem is that Tomee is trying to register the providers packaged in RestEasy client.  They don't need to be registered for the client to work.  The resteasy-client can be excluded from the client I'm trying to consume...then I created an uber-jar with the reasteasy dependencies and placed it in tome/lib.  Jars in tome/lib are excluded from scanning so the providers aren't registered.  The uber jar must contain all reasteasy-client dependencies because the class loader for tome/lib is not allowed to call back into the application.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working too. TomEE Plus 7.1.0 with RestEasy

That's what needs to be done:

1. To avoid "is not a SERVER provider" exception, you need to set system property "openejb.jaxrs.fail-on-constrainedto" to false. This feature is from CxfRsHttpListener class.
2. TomEE Plus 7.1.0 is using Java 8, but in "lib" folder there is a jar named "javaee-api-7.0-1.jar". When TomEE starts, it used all jars in that folder, no matter what you configured in maven or gradle as project dependencies. And there is a huge chance, that you will got JavaEE 7 classes.

   RestEasy 3.5.1.Final is an implementation of the JAX-RS-API 2.1 spec. So, with JavaEE7 you will got exception NoSuchFieldError SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE in MediaType.

   To avoid this, you need to use Resteasy 3.1.4.Final, which is an implementation of the JAX-RS-API 2.0.1 spec